# Apply style to wrapping <label> of checked checkbox

Tags: css, sass

I have a `<label>` tag that wraps checkbox. I want to define a style to that label if the checkbox is checked. Until now I've been relying on JavaScript but I see that there is a :has selector that might do what I want with CSS only

Here is my HTML:

```
<label><input type="checkbox name="param1"> Param 1</label>
```

Here is what I'm attempting in CSS:

```
label:has(input[type='checkbox']:checked){
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

However, it breaks my SCSS compiler before I even get to test it in a browser. I'm guessing that there is a CSS syntax error. My editor does highlight it as though there is an error, but I can't see where I've gone wrong.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

Comment: Scroll down to [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#Browser_compatibility) and you'll see that there's currently **no browser support** for the `:has` selector

Comment: It says in the first paragraph of the mozilla link: `In the current specification :has is not marked as part of the dynamic selector profile, which means it can not be used within stylesheets; only with functions like document.querySelector().` and as CSS can't look at parent elements, you're better off trying to do it with JavaScript if your HTML has to be written in this specific way, other wise you can do it if you re-arrange your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```css
input[type='checkbox'] {
  display:none;
}
label{
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
}
input[type='checkbox']:checked + label{
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="id">
<label for="id"></label>
```

Comment: This requires a change to the structure of the HTML in the original questions. It appears there is no easy way to style the `label` wrapper of an `input` based on its state.

Answer (score 0):

> Yes, css have `:has` selector but No browser supports it.

**I hope, this help to you:**

```css
input:checked + label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="param1" id="rad">
<label for="rad">Param 1</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

But if label is wrapping the input?
`<label> <input type="checkbox name="param1"> Param 1</label>`